# Subclassing Py2Neo's Node the Right Way

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

Suppose you have a very simple graph.

```
In [5]: node = py2neo.Node('LABEL', key='value')

In [6]: node_two = py2neo.Node('LABEL', key='value2')

In [7]: graph.create(py2neo.Relationship(node, 'IS_RELATED_TO', node_two))
```

At this point `node` is *bound*. Although the `node.bound` boolean seems to have been dropped in v3, you can see this by examining its `__remote__` property.

```
In [8]: node.__remote__
Out[8]: <RemoteEntity graph=u'http://localhost:7474/db/data/' ref=u'node/53983'>
```

Nodes are also dict-like, so they can be copied using double-splat unpacking (`**`). However, this does not copy `__remote__`, leaving `new_node` *unbound*.

```
In [9]: new_node = py2neo.Node(**node)

In [10]: new_node.__remote__ is None
Out[10]: True
```

This has the unfortunate side-effect that `new_node` cannot be used as the target of several methods expecting a bound node, for instance `match_one`:

```
In [11]: graph.match_one(new_node, 'IS_RELATED_TO', node_two)
TypeError: Nodes for relationship match end points must be bound
```

**Use Case**: Subclassing. If I subclass `py2neo.Node`, I must convert from `py2neo.Node` (which is returned by most `py2neo` methods) to my subclass. However, this then *unbinds* the node, which makes it useless to other `py2neo` methods, defeating the purpose of subclassing in the first place.

**Workaround**: If I set `new_node.__remote__ = node.__remote__`, this seems to work, and by definition binds `new_node`. However, I have a funny feeling about messing around with third-party double-underscore properties like this. I'm not sure if this is supported, and I'm positive it's undocumented. It could have side effects I'm not aware of.

#### Problems with the Official Solution

[According to the documentation on Node](http://py2neo.org/v3/types.html#nodes-relationships), this seems to be the official solution:

> In its initial state, a node is *unbound*. This means that it exists only on the client and does not reference a corresponding server node. A node is typically *bound* by [creating](http://py2neo.org/v3/database.html#py2neo.database.Transaction.create) it in a Neo4j database.

This suggests that the correct way to deal with my unbound copy (`new_node`) would be to use `graph.create`. However, this adds a new unwanted node to the graph with no label and the same properties as `node`. I could use `graph.merge` instead, to keep from creating an unwanted duplicate, but this would overwrite the properties in the graph with whatever is on `new_node`, which I don't always want.

So how are you supposed to convert `py2neo.Node` into any other type (or copy it) without totally derailing the py2neo workflow?

I have opened a related [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/nigelsmall/py2neo/issues/529), and will update this question with any information I get from the maintainer if he does not publish it here.